# How can i use cquery with spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, language-server-protocol

Is there a canonical/robust way to use cquery with spacemacs?
I recently swiched from vim to spacemacs and am not yet very familiar with emacs/spacemacs configuration/customization.
I have used cquery with vim before.
My projects have a compile_commands.json.